# Getting 'connect ECONNREFUSED' error when using Axios to call multi-tenant APIs in a Remix frontend

Tags: node.js, axios, fetch-api, remix

I have already developed a multi-tenant application. I'm using separate virtual hostnames to access each tenant(Ex: app1.lean.local, app2.lean.local, app3.lean.local etc) in my local development environment. Each tenant has a set of APIs. Now I'm trying to use those API endpoints in my new Remix frontend. When I try to call those APIs with Axios, it gives the "Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9002" error.

NodeJs version: 18.16.0,
Remix version: 1.13.0,
Axios version: 1.4.0

My host file

```
127.0.0.1 app1.lean.local
127.0.0.1 app2.lean.local
127.0.0.1 app3.lean.local
```

Axios request

```
axios.get('http://app1.lean.local:9002/api/v1/test')
```

There is no issue on the endpoint. I can access the endpoint via Postman

Comment: This means that Axios was not able to establish a TCP connection to the specified host and port. Have you checked whether your service is actually running on port 9002?